# Print correct and incorrect answers in a quiz

Tags: python

I'm just a beginner but I am having trouble with my code.
I am trying to get correct answer from my list but it won't print incorrect or correct correctly

```
#  List of questions in Quiz
question_List = ["How do you write number 1 in Maori?\n1.Tekau 2.Tahi 3.Ono 4.Rua",
                  "What is does tahi + tahi = ?\n1.Rua 2.Rimu 3.Ono 4.Tahi",
                  "How do you write blue in Maori?\n1.Kakariki 2.Kikorangi 3.Whero 4.Ma",
                  "What two colours make blue?\nMa + Whero 2.Kikorangi + Kowhai 3.Whero + Pararui 4.Ma + Mangu",
                  "Who was the god of the forest and birds?\n:1.Ranginui 2.Paptuanuku 3.Tane-Mahuta 4.Tangaroa",
                  "Who were Tane Mahutas Parents?\n1.Tangaroa + Ranguinui 2.Punga + Ranganui 3.Tangaroa + Rongo 4.Papatunuku + Ranganui"]

# List of Correct Answers
correct_Answer = [ "2", "1", "2", "2","3","4"]

# If user enters anything that is not an integer between 1 and 4 
def intcheck(question, low, high):
    valid= False
    while not valid:
        error= "Whoops! Please enter an integer between {} and {}".format(low, high)
        try:
            response = int(input("Please enter an integer between {} and {}:".format(low, high)))
            if low <= response <= high: 
                return response
            else:
                print(error)
                print()
        except ValueError:
              print(error)

# Get a question from the question list and print and loop
for question in question_List:
    print(question)

    Answer = intcheck("Please enter in an answer or press enter to quit", 1,4)
    print()

    for Answer in correct_Answer:
        print("correct")

     else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to change your last `for` statement into an `if`.

EDIT:

also, your `correct_Answer` list should contain integers instead of strings:

`correct_Answer = [2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]`

EDIT 2:

you want to compare the each answer with the corresponding correct_answer, see the code below:

```
# Get a question from the question list and print and loop
for idx, question in enumerate(question_List):
    print(question)

    Answer = intcheck("Please enter in an answer or press enter to quit", 1,4)
    print()

    if Answer == correct_Answer[idx]:
        print("correct")

    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Comment: if I do that it doesn't loop all the questions, if I do them as integers

Comment: sry for that. I edited my answer. With these changes, the program should do what you expect, right?

Comment: no it doesn't it just says correct, correct.......... when they aren't but thanks for trying

Comment: did you do both changes? correct_Answer has to contain integers for this to work

Comment: yes I've changed it but when I add your second edit it says idx not defined

Comment: I just need a simple way of doing it

Comment: you also need to change the outer `for` loop (see the second line in my code)